# oracle, underlying table/view code, ddl, show table

Tags: sql, oracle, ddl

I am wondering what the analog of the below teradata code is in Oracle. I want to find the underlying table or view ETL code. Basically, I want to find the code that is used to create the table/view. Is there a query to do this? Please send this code. I only know how to do this in the schema browser.  I am using ORacle SQL Developer, Schema Browser. Then clicked on SQL. 
I was looking for the underlying SQL on this table. This is the SQL code that creates the view. THis is the DDL. I just wanted to know how the view was created similarly, the analog to teradata code.

```
teradata
show VIEW Schema.Table
oracle
?
```

Comment: This Worked!!!!    `select text from ALL_VIEWS where upper(view_name) like upper('TABLE');`

Comment: if you're in the admin (sys or system schema) you can use all_views instead of user_schema which works for an ordinary schema where your related view exists. So if you connect to the right schema, @Hady Lattouf 's solution works also. By the way, `upper` is superfluous provided the table name in all capital letters such like `select text from all_views where view_name = 'MY_VIEW'`

Answer (score 1):

For views please execute this query:

```
select text from user_views where view_name = 'EMP_VIEW';
```

For tables you can execute this query:

```
select dbms_metadata.get_ddl( 'TABLE', 'EMP', 'SCOTT' ) from dual
```

Comment: I tried that....didn't work :( . Any ideas?

Comment: What did you get as a result?

Comment: @coder1167 it should be working, did you try your view name all in capital ..?

Comment: I got NULL back in the results. I only have read only access. Could this be the issue?

Comment: When you execute: select view_name from user_views can you find your view in the result?

Answer (score 0):

Oracle has a package `DBMS_METADATA` which is can be used to exctract DDL command to create it. You can use `GET_DDL` function to get table definition.

```
SELECT DBMS_METADATA.GET_DDL( 
           object_type => 'TABLE', 
           name => 'Table' , 
           schema => 'Schema') 
FROM DUAL;
```